# How to get third column, first row with Sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I run this command on a Oracle database server

> dbcli list-dbhomes

This results in me having 3 columns and 5 rows of information. I need a way in Sed to only get the 3rd column, 1st row. If you are running the command I need a way to only get the ID number that is displayed. I figured out how to get the first row of columns 1,2,and 3 with my code

```
dbcli list-dbhomes |  sed 's/ .*//'
```

but cannot figure out how to get only the 3rd row of the first column.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same kin your question and let us know then.

Comment: Sure, please check my edited question now.

Comment: `head` and `cut` may be cleaner. Something like `dbcli list-dbhomes | head -n 1 | cut -f 3 -d ' '`.

Comment: If your question would be closed here, I suggest to re-try on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

This should be an easy task for `awk`.

```
dbcli list-dbhomes |  awk 'FNR==1{print $3}'
```

***NOTE:*** This above commands considers that delimiter of output of `dbcli list-dbhomes` is space in case of some other delimiter we may need to change it in my code.

---

---

Using `head` + `cut`:

```
dbcli list-dbhomes | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 columns and 5 rows, and want to use sed to get the 3rd column, 1st row, you can use

```
sed -n 's/.* //;1p'
```

If by some chance you are using the words "row" and "column" differently from most people, you can use

```
sed -n 's/ .*//;3p'
```